# Laravel transaction not work when try to save 2 new item in Controller

Tags: laravel, transactions

I try to create 2 records in database in 2 tables.The 
2nd table has some triggers. 
I use transaction to manage 2 query
but when 2nd query is error, 1st query still work and save to database
Please help me, I'm trying to learn Laravel  6.x. I use only one database

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     DB::beginTransaction();

     try{
     $product= new Product;
      //...//
     $product->save(); // This query still work, save to database and doesn't rollback

     $ticket = new Ticket;
     //...//
     $ticket->save(); // This query is error

     DB::commit();
}catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException  $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
    return back()->with('error',$e->getMessage());
}
```

}

I'm sure that it catch the exception! The error message is shown but the rollback() not work

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have used DB record to work with the transaction, and Eloquent to work with database actions. As per my understanding you can not mix this. I said from my past experience.

I know Laravel documents are a bit vague on this.  But I have got success with below method as it uses the DB actions in the closure. This should work well.

**Note : Laravel Version 8.x**

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $product= new Product;
      //...//
     $product->save(); // This query still work, save to database and doesn't rollback

     $ticket = new Ticket;
     //...//
     $ticket->save(); // This query is error
}
```